# Как объединить команды в одну?

Tags: bash

Есть задача получить ID процесса и в дальнейшем с ним работать.
Следующий код работает:

```
PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep hal) 
PROCESS_ID=$(echo $PROCESS | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Есть ли возможность соединить команды в одну?
Что-то типа этого:

```
PROCESS_ID=$(ps aux | grep hal | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Но этот способ не корректен.

Comment: Что именно не корректно?

Comment: Вы правильно соединили команду в одну, не совсем понятно, в чем заключается вопрос.

Comment: @Vadik, обратите внимание что во второй команде переменная не экранирована кавычками, из за этого все символы табуляций и переносов становятся пробелом и весь текст выводится в одну строку.

Comment: @ipatev_nn, не понял где именно нужно было экранировать переменную. Дайте пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vadik, проблема в том, что объединённая команда не приводит к желаемому результату. В PROCESS_ID не записывается ID искомого процесса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PROCESS_ID=$(ps aux | grep hal | awk '{print $2}')
```

можно даже еще сократить(спасибо @ipatev_nn из комментариев ниже):

```
PROCESS_ID=$(ps aux |awk '/hal/{print $2}')
```

Comment: тогда и `grep` можно убрать `awk '/hal/{print $2}'`

Comment: @ipatev_nn точно, спасибо, добавлю в ответ

Comment: @Zt. Спасибо! Помогли!

Comment: @ipatev_nn и Вам большое спасибо!

Comment: @Эникейщик, раз Вы спрашиваете, то отвечу - времени сэкономил не много, но все что выручил - потратил на благое дело корректного оформления тела вопроса. Но большое спасибо Вам за грамотный вопрос по делу!

Answer (score 3):

Используя `pgrep`:

```
PROCESS_ID=$(pgrep hal)
```